# Subtracting two dates (including hours and minutes) considering only working time vba or Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to subtract two dates (including hours and minutes), but I only need to consider working hours. That is, I need to omit lunch time (from 13 to 14 hrs), weekends and hours after 18 hrs and before 9 hrs of the following day, in a working day (from Mo to Fr). Any thoughts?
I don't mind if it's an Excel formula or a vba code.
I have this formula, but it doesn't omit lunch time:

```
9*(NETWORKDAYS(initial_time;ending_time)-1)-24*((MOD(initial_time;1)-MOD(ending_‌​time;1)))
```

Comment: You must have tried something, you can't be the only one who has ever asked this question. Show your efforts and explain what is not working for you.

Comment: I have this formula, but it doesn't omit lunch time: 9*(NETWORKDAYS(initial_time;ending_time)-1)-24*((MOD(initial_time;1)-MOD(ending_time;1)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. It assumes an 8 hour work days for all but the start and end date. Also that start date/time is 9:00 or after and end date/time is 18:00 or earlier and that both are on a weekday.

```
=(NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)-2)*8+IF(MOD(A2,1)>0.58333,(TIME(18,0,0)-MOD(A2,1))*24,(TIME(18,0,0)-MOD(A2,1))*24-1)+IF(MOD(B2,1)>0.58333,(MOD(B2,1)-TIME(9,0,0))*24-1,(MOD(B2,1)-TIME(9,0,0))*24)
```

.58333 equates to 14:00. The formula:
  multiplies networkdays * 8 
+ hours from start date/time until 18:00 subtracting 1 hour if start time is before 14:00
+ hours from 9:00 until end date/time subtracting 1 hour if end time is after 14:00

Of course this doesn't take any holidays into account.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work perfectly. If one of the dates is out of the range 9-13 or 14-18 hrs, the formula fails. For example, if the starting date is 9:00:00 and the ending date is 13:10:00 of the same day, the formula throws 4,17, when it should be only 4. How can I fix that? @ClaytonMorris

Comment: Yep. As I said, it assumes that start / end times are within the "workday. It also assumes that the dates are different. I'll need some sample data to figure it out any further.